# How can I return nil instead of an error from a missing hash key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, key

I have a hash, and I'm looking for a certain key inside it. But sometimes `hash` itself can be nil. In this event, I don't want `hash["key"]` to return an `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` error. I want it to return `nil` instead.

With other similar situations, I can use `try`, like this: `nil.try(:key) => nil` but I can't get the same method to work with my hash.

In other words, I'm looking for a method that results in something like this:

```
> @hash = nil
> @hash.try(:["key"])
=> nil
```

Comment: Joe, excellent question. You have the good fortune of receiving a triumvirate of quality answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The various `to_X` methods are often convenient ways to quietly convert `nil`s to empty instances of what you're really interested in without complicated your logic with explicit conditionals.

In your case, you could take advantage of [`Hash#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-to_h) returning the hash itself and [`NilClass#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html#method-i-to_h) returning an empty Hash:

```
> hash = nil
> hash.to_h['key']
=> nil

> hash = { 'key' => 11 }
> hash.to_h['key']
=> 11
```

Sometimes this is less noisy than an explicit `if`, sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 7):

The situation you describe (`hash = nil`) is not a "missing hash key", it's not a hash at all.

In addition to the other answers, another way could be this in Ruby (2.3)

```
hash&.fetch("key", nil)
```

Or:

```
 (hash || {})["key"]
```

Both these will return `nil` if the hash is `nil` or if it's missing the key.

Comment: What does the `&` do?

Comment: @sagarpandya82, it's Ruby's [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/).

Comment: I don't believe `fetch` requires the second argument, `nil`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland without the second argument it will raise an error if the key's unknown. `{}.fetch(:foo) # => KeyError`

Comment: This makes it useful for situations when the key is needed, such as reading env vars.

Comment: I forgot `fetch(k)` didn't return `nil` (like `:[]` does) when it doesn't have a key `k` (but that's the whole idea :-) ). I've been playing around with `obj?["key"]`, trying to figure out why it can't be made to work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The syntax of the safe navigation operator is `foo&.bar(baz)`, so the syntax for accessing a hash value is `foo&.[](baz)`.

Comment: @Jörg, thank you. I am an idiot! I did try `foo&[](baz)`. What was I thinking?  Anyway, Max, `:[]` with the safe navigation operator could also be used: `{"key"=>1}&.[]("key") #=> 1; {"cat"=>9}&.[]("key") #=> nil; nil&.[]("key") #=> nil`.
.

Answer (score 3):

You could check if `@hash` is `nil` before using `@hash["key"]`, like this:

```
@hash = nil
@hash["key"] unless @hash.nil?
#=> nil
```

Comment: Nice, or `@hash && @hash["key"]`.

Answer (score 1):

To use try, you can do

```
@hash.try(:[], 'key')
```

or even

```
@hash&.[]('key')
```

if you are in ruby 2.3+